# Python: using regex to pull "product_id' from html javascript

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I am trying to pull this piece out of a javascript - "product_id' all of the product ids and assign them to a object or list

HTML -

```
                                                    <div class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">
<script type="text/javascript">
                    try {
                        var changeConfigurableStatus = true;
                        var stStatus = new StockStatus({"242":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92964"},"246":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92965"},"363":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92966"},"248":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92967"},"243":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92968"},"368":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92969"},"244":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92970"},"247":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92971"},"79":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92972"},"249":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"92973"}});
                    }
```

this is where my script is at currently -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import random
import re

session = requests.Session()
product_url = 'http://www.randomsite.com'
response = session.get(product_url)
soup = bs(response.text,'lxml')
div = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"attribute-item"})  # Select the divs with .attribute-item class
all_sizes = [x['data-value'] for x in div]  # Extract the 'data-value' attribute from all the divs with .attribute-item
size_chosen = random.choice(all_sizes)

print(all_sizes)
print(size_chosen)
```

I have been informed that i need to  "get the text inside the script by using `soup.find('script').text`, but after that you will most likely need regex to pick out the specific text you are looking for. " I am not sure where to begin in obtaining this. or how to implement this line into my code even.

Comment: Is that StockStatus a JSON string ?

Comment: You could also use this to find the script but I would use soup. `<script(?:\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])*?)+)?\s*>([\S\s]*?)</script\s*>`, then use something like `"product_id":"([^"]+)"` to get the values.

Comment: do you need more of the html? I'm not sure about json, how would i implement this into my script?

Comment: When you get the script string using soup stuff. Just run a find all using this regex `/"product_id":"([^"]+)"/g` where group 1, in parenthesis contains the value.

Comment: sin thank you so much was able to get it to work with this thank you so much. I used r = requests.get(url, headers=headers) then used the re.findall with your code, r.text